# Unable to translate cURL POST request to REST Assured request

Tags: java, web-services, api, rest-assured

Am trying to use REST-Assured to POST this cURL request:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @C:\Leo.jpg "http://<url>/<resource>?apikey={key}&outputMode=json&imagePostMode=raw"
```

Here is the REST-Assured request:

```
File file = new File(<file-path>);

InputStream docstream= getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("<image-file-name>.jpg");

Response resp = given()
                .header("Content-Length", file.length())
                .contentType(ContentType.BINARY)
                .contentType("multipart/form-data")
                .contentType("multipart/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .formParam("apikey", apiKey)
                .formParam("outputMode", "json")
                .formParam("imagePostMode", "raw")
                .content(docstream)
                .multiPart(new MultiPartSpecBuilder(docstream)
                        .fileName(file.getName())
                        .controlName("img_file")
                        .mimeType("image/jpeg").build())
                .post("<resource>")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .extract().response();
```

The cURL request returns the expected response from the server, but the REST-Assured request returns:

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:886)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1827)
```

Have tried changing the headers, multiPart several ways without any luck. Any help appreciated very much! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The apiKey, outputMode and imagePostMode parameters should be `queryParam`'s and not `formParam`.